# MySQL query with condition based on field value OR left join value

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I have 3 tables called "product", "product_group" and "product_category"

Products can be related to each other via the "product_group" table.

Products can appear in particular categories via the "product_category" table.

What I want to do is retrieve all products from a particular category, that either have a price, or contain one or more child products that have a price.

Here's an example of the tables:

```
product
=======
product_id      price
1               10.00
2               20.00
3               0.00
4               40.00
5               50.00
6               0.00
7               0.00
8               0.00
9               0.00
10              0.00
11              1.99

product_group
=============
product_id      child_product_id
6               1
6               2
7               3
7               4
8               9

product_category
================
category_id     product_id
1               5
1               6
1               7
1               8
1               10
2               11
```

This means that products 1 and 2 are children of product 6.  Products 3 and 4 are children of product 7.  Product 9 is a child of product 8.

Products 5, 6, 7, 8 and 10 are in category 1.

What I want is a query to return all products in category 1 that either have a price, or contain one or more children that have a price. So I would expect to get products 5, 6, 7.  Although products 8 and 10 are in category 1 I don't want these as they don't have a price, and they don't contain children that have a price.

I could post the query I have written so far using a combination of inner and left joins, but I fear that it's completely wrong.

Thank you for looking.

* Edit ***

I discovered my original query did work, I'd got the data in two of my columns mixed up.  Here is my original query below:

```
SELECT p.product_id 
  FROM product p 
  JOIN product_category c 
    ON c.product_id = p.product_id
   AND c.category_id = 1 
  LEFT
  JOIN product_group g 
    ON p.product_id = g.product_id 
  LEFT
  JOIN product AS p2 
    ON p2.product_id = g.child_product_id
   AND p2.price > 0
 WHERE p.price > 0 OR p2.product_id IS NOT NULL 
 GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Comment: I would say go ahead and post the query you have written.  Who cares if it's wrong?  That's why you're here, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it something like this:

```
SELECT p.product_id
  FROM product p
  JOIN product_category c
    ON c.product_id = p.product_id
   AND c.category_id = 1
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT g.product_id
           FROM product_group g
           JOIN product h
             ON h.product_id = g.child_product_id
            AND h.price > 0.00
          GROUP BY g.product_id
       ) r
    ON r.product_id = p.product_id
 WHERE p.price > 0 
    OR r.product_id IS NOT NULL
```

---

NOTES:

The JOIN to product_category gets us the restriction that the product has to be in category 1.

The inline view (derived table aliased as r) gets us a list of "parent" product_id that have have child_product_id which have a price.

We make that an OUTER join so we still get all the rows in category 1, we're just doing a match.

In the WHERE clause, we're filtering out rows, and keeping only those product that have a price, or that had a matching row from the inline view.

This is just one way, there are there are several ways to get an equivalent resultset.

This assumes that product_id is unique in the product table.

This also assumes that the (category_id,product_id) tuple is unique in the product_category table, that is, there won't be duplicates, e.g. (1,5),(1,5). If that assumption isn't valid, then we probably want to add a GROUP BY p.product_id at the end of the query, to get a distinct list.

Also, this only looks at direct children; it doesn't look to see if a grandchild (a child of the child) have a price.

Comment: Both your assumptions about product_id and the tuple being unique are correct.  I'll try the query later and let you know if it works - thank you

Comment: @MrCarrot: You can run the query in the inline view aliased as r separately, to verify it's returning a correct list (product_id that have a child product that have a price.) You can also modify the WHERE clause to check just the product price, and modify it so it checks only for a matching row from r.

Comment: Thanks @spencer7593, I am going to mark yours as the correct answer. However I discovered that my original query did work (I've edited my question to include it & I renamed the table aliases to make it comparable to yours) - I had the data mixed up in my columns after importing, hence I thought it was failing. I have EXPLAIN'ed your query and it has 5 steps.  My query has 4 steps but is using a filesort because of the GROUP BY. I'm not sure which is the most efficient but I now have a couple of working options. I'd be interested to hear your opinion regarding a comparison of the two. Thanks!

Comment: It's likely that your query is more efficient, since it doesn't have an inline view (derived table). But it's  really going to depend on the data distribution... if a given product_id has thousands of child products, rather than just a couple, there will be a lot of rows that need to be eliminated by the GROUP BY. The approach I used  limits the number of rows, but there's a cost of materializing the inline view. I'm going to give another alternative, as an update to my answer.